# CPU optimization of time-critical infinite loop in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop, time-critical

I am using following script to continuously log data from a sensor at 500Hz rate which requires an infinite loop. Naturally it keeps the CPU busy at over 30% for Windows laptop and up to 100% with Raspberry Pi 4. This problem is usually solved by implementing sleep() function, but considering I am recording live time-series data I can't afford loosing any data samples during the sleep time.

I would like to know how time-critical processes are handled not to overload CPU and how I can possibly optimize my code respectively.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pySerialTransfer import pySerialTransfer as txfer
import os
import time

# get file directory
__location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

buffLen = 2 ** 12                                                   # buffer size
maxFileSize = 100 * 10 ** 6                                         # maximum file size
print('Max file size: ' + str(maxFileSize/1000) + ' MB')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        link = txfer.SerialTransfer('COM3', 460800)
        link.open()
        # Wait serial to reset
        time.sleep(3)

        while True:
            # create a new file and open
            fileName = str(round(time.time())) + 'cms.bin'
            filePath = os.path.join(__location__, fileName)
            file = open(filePath, 'wb')
            print('New file: ' + fileName)
            # start writing data to new file
            while True:
                rawBuffer = bytearray()
                for count in range(buffLen):
                    # write only if new data available
                    if link.available():
                        rawBuffer.extend(bytes(link.rxBuff[0:11]))
                    elif link.status < 0:
                        print('ERROR: {}'.format(link.status))
                    else:
                        continue
                file.write(rawBuffer)
                # break to create a new file
                if os.path.getsize(fileName) > maxFileSize:
                    file.close()
                    break

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        link.close()
```

CPU load on Windows 10 PC:
[image: CPU load on Windows 10 PC]

CPU load on Raspberry Pi 4:
[image: CPU load on Raspberry Pi 4]

Answer (score 0):

If you are recording data, you don't need it in real time. I think what your concern is that you don't want to loose any data. Enter buffers. I see ~6MB buffer size used for the serial port interface. If you read data faster than that buffer fills up, you can be confident no data was lost due to sleep. And that is an empirical thing, and should be tested. You could go fancy and use clever back-out algorithm that tries to calculate least amount of sleep, but if your data rate is near constant, just find a sleep time where buffer is no more than 80% full when you start reading it (or less, if you expect bursts). So, as long as you drain data faster than it comes, nothing should be lost and your code can sleep easy ;)